# Is there a way to animate a Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.Position object value in xamarin.forms?

Tags: google-maps, animation, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maps

I just wanted to know if there was a way to animate changing the position of a map pin object using xamarin.forms.googlemaps? I've tried posting to their github page but got no response. I would really appreciate any help.

I've looked over [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/custom) documentation but I could not implement it since I keep getting an out of range error.

Below is a test animation I tried. I'm a complete novice at this so please forgive my code

```
var oAnimatePos = new Animation{
               {_curDriverPin.Position.Latitude,oCurDriverPos.Latitude, new Animation((v)=> _curDriverPin.Position = new Position(v,_curDriverPin.Position.Longitude)) },
               {_curDriverPin.Position.Longitude,oCurDriverPos.Longitude,new Animation((v)=> _curDriverPin.Position = new Position(_curDriverPin.Position.Latitude,v)) }
            };
            oAnimatePos.Commit(this, "AnimateDriver", 16, 300, Easing.CubicInOut);
```

Comment: Add the code you are having a problem with to your question

Comment: Hi, I've added it to the post